# Magento 2 load multiselect attribute values in product list

Tags: attributes, php-7, magento2.4

I am trying to load multiple values of Color attribute in product list phtml file with this code:

```
<?php echo __('Color: ') . $_product->getAttributeText('color'); ?>
```

But I get array error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

Any help please? This is magento 2.4 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
$color = $_product->getAttributeText('color');
        if ($color) {
            if (is_array($color)) {
                echo implode(',', $color);
            } else {
                echo $color;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Working great! Thank you so much!